# Grand Central Dispatch equivalent for omp_get_thread_num

Tags: openmp, grand-central-dispatch

Does the Grand Central Dispatch API allow an execution context (thread) to query any thread-specific state during runtime? Specifically, is there a GCD equivalent to the OpenMP call
`omp_get_thread_num()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to execute an operation n-times to a bunch of things (like an map operation), you can use `dispatch_apply`.

```
dispatch_apply(10, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^(size_t index) {
    void * my_thing =  my_tings[index];
    // ...
});
```